# Python 2.7 requests REST API call not working same as curl

Tags: python, python-2.7, rest, curl, python-requests

I am trying to do a curl post query using requests python 2.7, however the API response differently using curl vs. requests lib.

The post query is pretty simple a file and name-value-pair data as the API params.

Below is the curl multipart post request:

```
 curl -uadmin:blabla123 -X POST 127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/6a0ab661-1c43-43ed-b07f-a564f6bcb5ca/children -F filedata=@file1.txt -F name=document__55;nodeType=content
```

The python 2.7 code is as below:

```
import requests
from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth, HTTPDigestAuth
from config import USER, PASSWD

def createDocument( documentFilename, documentMetadata, targetFolderNodeId):
    '''
    Uploads a file and its meta-data to the CMIS server under the specified
     target folder
    '''
    with open(documentFilename, 'rb') as file:
        files = {'file': file}
        # createURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{0}/children'.format( targetFolderNodeId )
        createURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/6a0ab661-1c43-43ed-b07f-a564f6bcb5ca/children'
        data =  {
                  "name":"document__55",
                  "nodeType":"cm:content", 
                }
        response = requests.post( createURL, data = data, files = files, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASSWD) )
        print(response)
        print(response.json)
        print(response.text)

createDocument('file1.txt', '', '')
```

Curl returns 200 http code but the script oddly returns 400.

Any help is much appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

At a first glace the reasons for that script failing vs curl working could be more than one:

- `nodeType=content` in the curl, while `"nodeType":"cm:content"` in the script
- there's an additional comma in the script's payload second line
- you're not setting the *Content-Type* header as `multipart/form-data` in the script, which `curl`'s `-F` option actually does

Also, the endpoint should provide a verbose error along with the 400 response. If it does, that could be helpful to identify the error cause.

Comment: None of the above in fact in the curl I have -F filedata=@file1.txt but in the script I have files = {'file': file} which is not the same so I just had to use files = {'filedata': file} :)

Answer (score 0):

in fact in the curl I have -F filedata=@file1.txt but in the script I have files = {'file': file} which is not the same so I just had to use files = {'filedata': file} :)

```
def createDocument( documentFilename, documentMetadata, targetFolderNodeId):
    '''
    Uploads a file and its meta-data to the CMIS server under the specified
     target folder
    '''
    with open(documentFilename, 'rb') as file:
        files = {'filedata': file}
        createURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/nodes/{0}/children'.format( targetFolderNodeId )
        data =  {
                  "name":"document__77",
                  "nodeType":"cm:content"
                }
        response = requests.post( createURL, data = data, files = files, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(USER, PASSWD) )
        print(response)
        print(response.json)
        print(response.text)
        print(response.headers)
        # print([i for i in dir(response) if 'header' in i])
```